# According to Catholicism, to what extent is the spiritual growth of a Christian impaired by his/her lack of devotion to Mary and the Saints?

Tags: catholicism, virgin-mary, intercession-of-saints, devotion, spiritual-growth

According to Catholicism, if a Christian lacks devotion to Mary and the Saints, is he or she spiritually "handicapped" or "missing out" spiritually?

For example, let's suppose that a Christian has devotion to the Father, the Son and and the Holy Spirit (or possibly subsets of them in the case of non-Trinitarians). Let's say also that this Christian only prays to God in the name of Jesus, his mindset is constantly set on becoming a better disciple of Christ and he constantly seeks the guidance of the Holy Spirit. However, he has no devotion to Mary or the Saints, to the point that he doesn't even think of them at all, they are just not part of his daily thoughts. His only devotion is God, and God alone. **According to Catholicism, would such a Christian be able to live a spiritually fulfilled life and achieve full spiritual maturity?** Or on the contrary, due to his lack of devotion to Mary and the Saints, would such a Christian inevitably encounter a road block to his spiritual growth, which will become evident to him as a feeling of *"I feel like I'm missing something but I'm not sure what it is"*?

***Note:** For those interested in the Protestant perspective on this issue, please see [How do Protestants explain the benefits of Marian devotion and praying the Rosary experienced by Catholics?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/87520/50422)*

Comment: trying to write an answer to this question, I think you've really got two questions here. One about Mary and another about the Saints; but I don't expect you'd know that until you read up on Catholic devotions and mariology.

Comment: One of the aspects of Christ(ianity) is meekness; being aware that there are human beings as oneself, which are far holier than one will ever be, is certainly a humbling experience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Whether Mary is necessary to the spiritual growth of a Christian

**Objection 1**. It would seem that the spiritual life of a Christian could be equally as rich without the admixture of devotions to the Blessed Virgin Mary.  Our Lord, as the one Mediator is sufficient for salvation and therefore all the spiritual growth one needs is wrapped up in salvation as one doesn't need *more* than salvation to be saved

**Objection 2**. Devotions to the Blessed Virgin Mary is always to be figured secondarily to true devotion to Our Lord.  The Lords Prayer is a complete summary of the life of prayer, whereas the Hail Mary is just praise followed by petition.

**Objection 3**. The Apostolic Fathers, especially those who knew Our Lord best; as well as Our Lady, would not have had recourse to the devotions we have today because those devotions developed over the course of centuries and those devotions were directed *through them* which would have been an odd sort of devotion for someone who personally knew Jesus.

**On the Contrary**.  St. Louis De Montfort states in True Devotion to Mary:

> ALL our perfection consists in being conformed, united, and consecrated to Jesus Christ; and therefore the most perfect of all devotions is, without any doubt, that which the most perfectly conforms, unites, and consecrates us to Jesus Christ. Now, Mary being the most conformed of all creatures to Jesus Christ, it follows that, of all devotions, that which most consecrates and conforms the soul to our Lord is devotion to His holy Mother, and that the more a soul is consecrated to Mary, the more is it consecrated to Jesus.

**I answer that** Mary is a model for the Church. St. John Paul II refers to Mary as a model for the Church sixteen times in his encyclical *Redemptoris Mater*

> Mary is present in the Church as the Mother of Christ, and at the same time as that Mother whom Christ, in the mystery of the Redemption, gave to humanity in the person of the Apostle John. Thus, in her new motherhood in the Spirit, Mary embraces each and every one in the Church, and embraces each and every one through the Church. In this sense Mary, Mother of the Church, is also the Church's model.
>
> https://www.vatican.va/content/john-paul-ii/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_jp-ii_enc_25031987_redemptoris-mater.html

Without her model as a prototype, man is bound to flounder, creating his own religions fashioned off his own vices. He may be lucky, like G.K. Chesterton, to found his own heresy and discover it was orthodoxy, but much more likely he'll found something else.

**Reply to objection 1**.  St. Louis explains the purpose of following Mary to Jesus,

> It is an easy way. It is the way which Jesus Christ Himself trod in coming to us, and in which there is no obstacle in arriving at Him. It is true that we can attain to divine union by other roads; but it is by many more crosses, and strange deaths, and with many more difficulties, which we shall find it hard to overcome. We must pass through obscure nights, through combats, through strange agonies, over craggy mountains, through cruel thorns, and over frightful deserts. But, by the path of Mary, we pass more gently and more tranquilly.

Being an "easy way" doesn't mean it is always comfortable, but Catholics who do these things believe that certain prayer and devotions have certain "signal graces" attached to them.  For instance, one who perseveres in praying the Rosary may not die without last rites (one of the 15 promises of the Rosary).

> 6. Those who recite my Rosary devoutly, applying themselves to the consideration of its sacred mysteries, shall never be conquered by misfortune. In His justice, God will not chastise them; nor shall they perish by an unprovided death, i.e., be unprepared for heaven. Sinners shall convert. The just shall persevere in grace and become worthy of eternal life.
>
> https://dominicanfriars.org/the-15-promises-of-the-rosary/

**Reply to Objection 2** The Lords Prayer is the summary of Christian Prayer, but a prayer through an advocate, a most gracious advocate (as St. Bernard might say) is an effective tool at making your case before God.

> ... in heaven and on earth everything, even to God Himself, is subject to the Blessed Virgin, they mean to say that the authority which God has been well pleased to give her is so great, that it seems as if she has the same power as God, and that her prayers and petitions are so powerful with God, that they always pass for commandments with His Majesty, who never resists the prayer of His dear Mother, because she is always humble and conformed to His Will.
>
> [True Devotion to Mary](https://www.ecatholic2000.com/montfort/true/devotion.shtml#__RefHeading___Toc332751727)

Given Mary's intercessory power, Catholics should pray Hail Mary *with* Our Father as much as possible, which is a very natural thing to do in almost every Catholic devotion (Rosary, Divine Mercy Chaplet, when Praying for the Pope's intentions, etc...), avoiding the Hail Mary is about as fruitful as avoiding pants.

**Reply to Objection 3** The apostolic Fathers may not have recourse to the Blessed Virgin's intercessory power in Heaven until her Assumption, but they certainly had recourse to her earthly power, grace and wisdom.  If the stories be true, and she was Conceived without Original Sin, then her prudence would have been infinite.  Failure to turn to her in trouble would have been foolishness.

---

Now, as to the rest of the saints, I could copy and paste the above and make it to a lesser extent, but Mary is the model for all the saints.  It is possible to be consecrated to St. Joseph, have a devotion to St. John the Baptist, or a saint whose life touches yours in a personal way, but Mary (and Joseph) are the Universal saints whose intercession everyone who ever was can understand, benefit from and grow in love of Christ through.

Comment: Your response to the three objections provides a clear insight into how Catholics view Mary.  Useful information.

Comment: How about devotion to the Apostle Paul, who said "Be imitators of me, as I am of Christ." (1 Cor. 11:1) ?

Comment: @spirit I think you should ask "What does devotion mean, according to the Catholic Church?"

Comment: The quotation in your reply to objection 2 looks as if the degree of equality it suggests goes well beyond papal teaching, in a similar way that the title *Co-Redemtrix* is used by some Catholics but the current Pope and his predecessor would never use it.

Comment: @henry I certainly hope not.  True Devotion to Mary has been around for a long time.  If they wanted to ban the book they're certainly at liberty to do so.  St. John Paul II said (and I quoth the wiki) that, 'reading this book had been a "decisive turning point" in his life'  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_Devotion_to_Mary

Comment: @PeterTurner St. Montfort cited the word "other roads", is Mary the "narrow roads or narrow gate" leading the Christ? The Church Father's teaches Mary symbolizes the "neck", if the Head of the Church is Jesus, and the Church is the Mystical Body, the "neck" is what connects the two, and it is a narrow path. So, Mary is the "narrowgate", did St. Montfort teaches this?

Answer (score 0):

According to Catholicism, to what extent is the spiritual growth of a Christian impaired by his/her lack of devotion to Mary and the Saints?

The simple answer is "wisdom and grace". A Christian cannot become like Christ, if one is lacking in wisdom and grace. St.Luke describe Jesus at the Temple, having the zealousness to answer question or to preach the good news, but, Jesus still not reach the heights, as St.Luke stated, Jesus "grew in wisdom and grace".

> **The Boy Jesus at the Temple**

> …51Then He went down to Nazareth with them and was obedient to them. But His mother treasured up all these things in her heart. 52And Jesus grew in wisdom and stature, and in favor with God and man.-Luke2:51-52

Who is the source of "grace and wisdom" according to Catholicism?

Mary is the Mediatrix of all graces and the Seat of Wisdom.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediatrix_of_all_graces

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seat_of_Wisdom

But the simple answer can be found in the words of Pope Francis..

> "Do not be orphan."-Pope Francis

> VATICAN CITY — Pope Francis told a group of young people discerning a religious vocation to never go it alone, but always stay by their mother, Mary.

"A Christian without Our Lady is an orphan. Also a Christian without the church is an orphan. A Christian needs these two women, two mothers, two virgins: the church and Our Lady," he said Saturday.

> https://www.ncronline.org/blogs/francis-chronicles/christians-without-mary-their-life-are-orphans-pope-says

And in the words of the late famous exorcist Fr.Gabrielle Amorth,

> "Anyone who goes to Mary and pray the rosary cannot be touch by Sata."-Fr.Gabrielle Amorth

If a Christian is not an orphan, and have a powerful Mother, that Satan is powerless against, can a Christian having a Marian devotion follow the footsteps of Christ up to Calvary embracing the Way of the Cross?

The answer is YES! and the thousands of Saints if not all Catholic Saints have Marian devotion, a testament that one cannot become a Saint, if one do not embraced Mary as their Spiritual Mother.

So, in closing, let us remeber the simple words of Pope Francis.

"Do not be orphan." because the agonizing Jesus gave us one, the mosr precious gift of all...His beloved Mother, who did not left him, from "womb to tomb".

> "Behold your Mother". -John1:27